# RabbitMq - Forward messages on a exchange to queues running on another host

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm wondering... Can I create (in my code) rules to bind an exchange to a queue (possibly) in another server or virtual host. I mean, lets consider a exchange named A, that should forward messages assign to it to a queue named B that lies on another server. Is this possible? Can you provide some examples? Thank you!

Comment: Check out RabbitMQ documentation for the Shovel plugin or the Federation plugin.  Both will do what you are describing.

Answer (score 1):

The shovel plugin is ideal for this use-case and can be configured either statically or dynamically.

See the rabbitmq docs [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel.html) to learn more about shovel administration.